# How to repeat a series of numbers with shape (n,1) as an array of n unique numbers repeated by 4 times with a shape of (n,1)

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, repeat, tile

I think this is a relatively straightfoward question but I've been struggling with getting this to the right shape.
I have a series/dataframe column structured as:

```
0         0.127883
1         0.129979
2         0.130000
            ...   
1000   0.090000
```

I want to turn this into:

```
[[array([0.12788259, 0.12788259, 0.12788259, 0.12788259])]
 [array([0.12997902, 0.12997902, 0.12997902, 0.12997902])]
 [array([0.13, 0.13, 0.13, 0.13])]
 ...
 [array([0.09, 0.09, 0.09, 0.09])]
 [array([0.09, 0.09, 0.09, 0.09])]
 [array([0.09, 0.09, 0.09, 0.09])]]
```

Essentially, I am trying to create a matrix with shape (n,1) containing the input number repeated by 4 times, but wrapped in an array. I have only been able to get to the following:

`arr_out = np.array(np.tile(np.array(a).reshape(-1,1),4))`

and the corresponding result, which while looks the same, is missing the comma in between variables and without the 'array' wrapper:

```
     [[1.12788259 1.12788259 1.12788259 1.12788259]
     [1.12997902 1.12997902 1.12997902 1.12997902]
     [1.13       1.13       1.13       1.13      ]
     ...
     [1.09       1.09       1.09       1.09      ]
     [1.09       1.09       1.09       1.09      ]
     [1.09       1.09       1.09       1.09      ]]
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: What you have shown is a set of arrays like you want, the only difference is how Python prints NumPy arrays (without commas, etc.). The default collection type in Python is actually a List, which may be what you are expecting here. In that case, put a `.tolist()` at the end of your line of code. Otherwise, keep the NumPy array and just print it differently.

Comment: Thanks. The main issue is that this output has a shape of (n,4) rather than (n,1) which is what I need it to be.

Comment: @technoking but why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about this method:

```
import numpy as np
ser = np.arange(5, dtype = float) # Edit: added argument 'dtype = float'
arr = ser.repeat(4).reshape(-1, 4)
l = list(arr)
ob_arr = np.array([None for i in range(len(l))], dtype = object)
for i in range(len(ob_arr)):
    ob_arr[i] = l[i]
```

output:

```
array([array([0., 0., 0., 0.]), array([1., 1., 1., 1.]),
       array([2., 2., 2., 2.]), array([3., 3., 3., 3.]),
       array([4., 4., 4., 4.])], dtype=object)
```

Comment: Thanks - this is really close to what I need! Only issue is I need the array to be a float. But setting dtype = float throws a ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.